Why my projects has suddenly stopped running after adding the Material design library?
After adding the implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.13.0-alpha03' dependency to include the material design library for a show password button in my EditText, the project successfully synced without any errors related to this change. However, now the project fails to load on any device or emulator.
Upon removing the implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.13.0-alpha03' dependency from the Gradle file and eliminating the TextInputLayout code from the activity_main file, the project runs successfully on all devices and emulators.
The following is my build.gradle file
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace 'com.hafee.learningproject'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hafee.learningproject"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.1'
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.13.0-alpha03'
    implementation libs.androidx.core.ktx
    implementation libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx
    implementation libs.androidx.activity.compose
    implementation platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom)
    implementation libs.androidx.ui
    implementation libs.androidx.ui.graphics
    implementation libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview
    implementation libs.androidx.material3
    implementation libs.androidx.appcompat
    implementation libs.androidx.constraintlayout
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.espresso.core
    androidTestImplementation platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom)
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4
    debugImplementation libs.androidx.ui.tooling
    debugImplementation libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest
}

Folowing is the code of TextInputLayout in my activity_main.xml file
<!-- Password Edittext -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_password"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
        android:padding="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/username_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username_text"
        android:scrollbarSize="25dp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/border_password"
            /> </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

I experimented with different versions of the dependency and thoroughly checked for errors, but none of the changes resolved the issue. I have also checked related questions on this topic but nothing worked either.

If you are using version catalog for your other dependencies, you must use it for the new dependency as well: https://developer.android.com/build/dependencies

No, I am not using version catalog for other dependencies.
